# How I can use a Powershell Script for copy data from position A to position B?

Tags: powershell, unc, get-childitem, copy-item

I want to use a Powershell script for copy a folder recursive to a other position. This must the Powershell todo:

- copy file and folders from position A to position B
- UNC PAth must have (for example \net.local\Files\EDV)
- On position B must all empty Folder clear
- The structure of position B must equals with postion A
- Missing folders should be created on B .
- It should only copy files that are older than 180 days
- The Script must create a logfile with Information about the filename and path, File size, file date

I have begun with this script:

```
$a = '\\serverA\folderA'
$b = '\\serverB\folderB'

#This copies the files
Get-ChildItem $a -Recurse -File | Foreach_Object {Copy-Item $_ -Destination $b}

#Removes empty files
Get-ChildItem $b -File | Foreach-Object {IF($_.Length -eq 0) {Remove-Item $_}}
```

I need help..

Comment: Consider to use robocopy: https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc733145%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

*This code copies a directory to another directory, the rest should be straight forward. In `$toreplace` every backslash should be escaped with an extra backslash.*

```
$a = [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]'C:\Users\oudou\Desktop\dir'
$b = [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]'C:\Users\oudou\Desktop\dir_copy'


function recursive($a,$b)
{
    foreach ($item in @(Get-ChildItem $a.FullName))
    {
        if($item -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo])
        {
            if ( -not (Test-Path $item.FullName.Replace($a.FullName,$b.FullName)))
            {
                New-Item -ItemType Directory $item.FullName.Replace($a.FullName,$b.FullName)
            }
            $dest = Get-ChildItem $item.FullName.Replace($a.FullName,$b.FullName)
            $dest
            recursive($item, $dest)
        }
        else
        {
            [string]$y = $item.FullName
            $toreplace = "C:\\Users\\oudou\\Desktop\\dir"
            $replace = "C:\Users\oudou\Desktop\dir_copy"
            $y -replace $toreplace , $replace            
            Copy-Item  $item.FullName  ($item.FullName -replace $toreplace , $replace)
        }
    }
}


recursive $a $b
```